# Melodic Minor Modes

Tags: theory, scales, modes

[Do modes exist in the harmonic / melodic minor scales?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/46114/do-modes-exist-in-the-harmonic-melodic-minor-scales/46116#46116)

This question needs to be brought back to life.

The answer to the question above is wrong... the chart is right, but the answer is wrong... here is what I got for the melodic minor modes

1. Melodic Minor
2. Dorian b9
3. Lydian Augmented
4. Lydian Dominant
5. Mixolydian b6
6. Aeolian Diminished **or** Half-Diminished
7. Altered Dominant **or** Superlocrian

Also, if anyone has an easier naming convention, I'd gladly adopt it. I'm not a huge fan of calling a mode by the alterations from another mode... e.g. `Dorian b9`... I find a descriptive term like `Lydian Dominant` to be much easier to picture. So if you have better names for `Dorian b9` and `Mixolydian b6` that would be great!

Comment: One of your scale names on your list is a nonstandard - your "Aeolian Diminished" - may I suggest changing into "Locrian ♮2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to your names -

2. Phrygian nat.2 / Javanese / Dorian b2 (rather than b9) / *Phrygidorian*.
3. Lydian #5 (aka aug.)
4. Lydian b7 / Acoustic scale / Mixolydian #4 / Overtone / *Lydomyxian*.
5. Melodic major / Hindu / *Mixaeolian*.
6. Locrian nat.2 / *Aeolocrian*.
7. -as you already say.

Few of which trip off the tongue! I suppose the italicised names are fairly apposite, and where did 'acoustic' came from?? So, unless someone wants to re-christen them with completely new names, we're basically stuck trying to describe them as bastardisations of existing mode names.

Comment: I'm always confused whether to call things `b2` or `b9`, `#4` or `b13` etc.